# Problem with »Scion« not found

Tags: eclipse, haskell, eclipse-fp

When I try to use HaskellFP for Eclipse, I always get a popup that the Scion server failed to build. In the console appears the following message:

> cabal: The program ghc version >=6.4 is required but it could not be found.

I have the latetest Haskell platform installed. All programs (but not eclispe) are installed in `~/usr`.

I am new to Eclipse. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can find the instruction for scion on this page:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsefp/files/EclipseFP%202%20branch/2.0.4/

"Scion: EclipseFP relies on Scion, the Haskell IDE library, for a lot of its functionality. See http://code.google.com/p/scion-lib/ for more information."

Comment: I have double checked it: scion is installed on my machine. But thank you for the help.